# Windows Mobile 6.5 launch bluetooth manager programmatically

Tags: c#, compact-framework, bluetooth, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm working on application for Windows Mobile 6.5 and would like to be able to launch the Bluetooth Manager from my application using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file, args), but I cannot determine application I need to launch.

I've been looking at the remote process viewer to determine what application is being run when I click Start > Settings > Connections > Bluetooth, but don't see any change after refreshing.

Can anyone tell me what I need to launch to achieve this?

Windows Mobile 6.5 Pro, Compact framework 3.5, c#

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why are you developing a WinMo app *now*?

Comment: @spartan018: perhaps because there are still lots of those things out there; or at least enough to justify the effort?

Comment: @Andrew Obviously there are a lot of WinMo devices out there, but how many are of those are running 6.5? How many users out of that number actually install apps? And that number is guaranteed to only get smaller. I don't personally see any merit in developing for a dying platform. Just my two cents, and why I originally mentioned that I was asking out of pure curiosity. I don't expect everyone to agree with me.

Comment: @spartan018: I was just offering the only response that seems to make sense.

Comment: @spartan018 - I'm in the rugged mobile computing area, so Phone 7 doesn't really apply to the devices we target.  All our devices are CE or WinMo.

Comment: @pitprog Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you for entertaining my curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process.Start(@"\Windows\ctlpnl.exe", "cplmain.cpl, 23, 0");